# Should I use one or two databases for one app?

Tags: sql, database, join, datatable, project

I am a student in second year of computer science and mathematics.
We are asked for a project to make an app for management of student registrations and grades.
The registration part take into account registration AND re-registration.
For now I am trying to conceive the database of the app with MySQL using Xampp.

I have overall 2 questions.

1- Should I make separate database for the registration and the grades?

2- In a database, is it best to make a big table, with informations about  the students or multiple tables(personal info, academic info...).

My opinion :

If I decide to go for a unique database, I have to make different tables. But I am not sure if it won't make the app difficult to use, since registration and grades are managed by different people.

However if I have two databases, at least for the registration part, I can just have a big table. But I'm afraid making the joint will become difficult.

Thank you.

Comment: Think of table as an object. A student is an object, a registration is an object, a course is an object, a relationship between a student and a course is an object, so-and-so-forth. Approaching in this manner will help think through it. AS for your first question, no. This should all exist in a single database. I would think of the database as 1:1 with an application. If your server is hosting data for 4 applications, then 4 databases would make sense.

Comment: Okay thank you!. So overall it's best to go for a database and a table for each object!

Comment: Yes. 1 Database for your 1 application. 1 table for each thing you define as an object. An object is something that has attributes that are expressed as columns. You may find that you iterate a few times on this design as you build this out, that's very normal. No one gets a schema perfect right out of the gate. In the end you should end up with a DB design that is static and only grows in number of rows (not number of tables, databases, or columns). If you find yourself implementing application logic that has to create a new column dynamically, you lost the thread.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to have two databases for the same app, just distribute the tables that will be part of your application. In the case of students, it is always interesting to normalize your table, see the most used examples [here](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).